# Ajax function to search in DB with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, path

Hello guys I'm trying to make this function work but itsn't, what I need is after I leave focus of 1 input the function should search in DB for that value if exist return the information of that person if not exist allow to fill the information manually... anyways this is what I have:

```
$('#cedula').focusout(function(){
    var cedula = $('#cedula').val();
    if($.trim(cedula) !== ''){
        $.post('ajax/buscar.php', {cedula: cedula}, function(data){
            if(data !== ''){
                console.log("I found this " + data);
                var mitad = data.split('/');
                $('#nombre').val(mitad[1]);
                $('#telefono').val(mitad[2]);   
                $('#serial').focus();   
                $('#cliente_enc').prop("checked", true);

            }else{
                console.log("I didn't got any data =( for this ID" + cedula);
                $('#cliente_enc').prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    }
    if($('#cedula').val().length >= 5)
        $('#barra').css('width','15%');
});
```

my php buscar.php is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cedula']) === true && empty($_POST['cedula']) === false){
        $ced = trim($_POST['cedula']);
        require dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'../db/connect.php';
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cedula = :cedula;");
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':cedula' => $ced
        ));

        $resultado = $statement->fetch();
        if($resultado != false){
            echo $resultado[1]."/".$resultado[2];
        }else
            echo "";
    }
```

my connect.php file:

```
<?php
use Project\Helpers\Config;
require dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'../app/Config.php';

$config = new Config;
$config->load('config.php');

try {
    //Datos para realizar la conexion
    $dbhost = $config->get('db.hosts.local');
    $dbname = $config->get('db.name'); 
    $dbuser = $config->get('db.user'); 
    $dbpass = $config->get('db.password'); 

    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
}   
?>
```

and my Config.php file:

```
<?php 
/*Esta clase permite cargar las configuraciones del sistema*/
namespace Project\Helpers;
class Config
{
    protected $data;
    protected $default = null;
    public function load($file){
        $this->data = require $file;
    }
    public function get($key, $default = null){
        $this->default = $default;
        $segments = explode('.', $key);
        $data = $this->data;

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            if(isset($data[$segment])){
                $data = $data[$segment];
            }else{
                $data = $this->default;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    public function exists($key){
        return $this->get($key) !== $this->default;
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the config.php file:

```
<?php  
return [
    'db' => [
        'hosts' => [
            'local' => 'localhost',
            'externo' => '217.169.87.94',
        ],
        'name' => 'cl55',
        'user' => 'gord',
        'password' => 'Darker1356'
    ],
    'mail' => [
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com'
    ]
];
?>
```

I have the database and the person with the ID I'm testing but I keep getting empty data...

Here's a pic of my project structure

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGRte.png)

Comment: Is your $.post request hitting the buscar.php? Try echoing back some dummy data, like `echo "test";` just to see if it's getting there. The jQuery looks alright but I'm not convinced with the PHP.

Comment: Yes, I put echo "test ajax"; after the SELECT query and in the console it's logging "I found this test ajax" @xCRKxTyPHooN

Comment: Okay that's good, your jQuery looks to be working find so it's just your SQL/PHP.

Comment: I don't think your php is right, take a look at how they handle it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: I'm think my problem is with the paths of the 'require' to connect the database and the config file but I don't know for sure @xCRKxTyPHooN